# How to override style in Bootstrap3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to override the `line height` value of `20`

**bootstrap.css Line 4245**

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {

  line-height: 20px;
}
```

My feeble attempt:

**Site.Master**

```
<body class="bsoverride">
```

**Site.css**

```
.bsoverride.navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 29px;
}
```

Comment: Useful pro-tips: we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Also: [useful reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) (and an interesting discussion too!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space between `.bsoverride` and `.navbar-nav` . Like that

```
.bsoverride .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 29px;
}
```

And you must write that css after bootstrap's css

Comment: That was it, thank you! BTW, does the class attribute need to be in the body element?

Comment: No, it is not. You can also skip it if it is not necessary.